# Can't get integer from JTextField

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to get an integer from a `JTextField`, but I keep getting a `NumberFormatException`. I used the code below:

```
JTextField price = new JTextField();
price.addActionListener(new ComboListener());
String inputText = price.getText();
int inputPrice = Integer.parseInt(inputText);
```

Every site says this is the proper way to do it, so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

edit: The full code is here:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RatePanel extends JPanel {

    private double[] rate; // exchange rates
    private String[] currencyName;
    private JLabel result;

    public RatePanel() {
        currencyName = new String[]{"Select the currency..",
            "European Euro", "Canadian Dollar",
            "Japanese Yen", "Australian Dollar",
            "Indian Rupee", "Mexican Peso"};

        rate = new double[]{0.0, 1.2103, 0.7351,
            0.0091, 0.6969, 0.0222, 0.0880};

        JLabel title = new JLabel("How much is that in dollars?");
        title.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        title.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 20));
        add(title);
        add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 100)));
        JLabel enter = new JLabel("Enter cost of item");
        enter.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        enter.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 20));
        add(enter);
        JTextField price = new JTextField();
        price.addActionListener(new BoxListener());
        price.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
        add(price);
        add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 100)));
        JLabel select = new JLabel("Select a currency: ");
        select.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        select.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 20));
        add(select);
        JComboBox Cbox = new JComboBox(currencyName);
        Cbox.addActionListener(new ComboListener());
        Cbox.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
        add(Cbox);
        String index = Cbox.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }

    public class BoxListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            String inputText = price.getText();
            int inputPrice = Integer.parseInt(inputText);
        }
    }

    public class ComboListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event, String index, double inputPrice, double[] rate) {
            double finalPrice = 0;
            switch (index) {
                case "European Euro":
                    finalPrice = inputPrice * rate[1];
                    break;
                case "Canadian Dollar":
                    finalPrice = inputPrice * rate[2];
                    break;
                case "Japanese Yen":
                    finalPrice = inputPrice * rate[3];
                    break;
                case "Australian Dollar":
                    finalPrice = inputPrice * rate[4];
                    break;
                case "Indian Rupee":
                    finalPrice = inputPrice * rate[5];
                    break;
                case "Mexican Peso":
                    finalPrice = inputPrice * rate[6];
                    break;
            }

            result = new JLabel(inputPrice + "USD equals " + finalPrice
                    + index);
            add(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, do I assume this is the "actual" code you're using or just example, because if it's the "actual" code, then it's no wonder it won't work, as the text field is unlikely to have an actual (valid) value when you try and parse it

Comment: Normally you'd use a `ActionListener` or some other event to determine when you should check the field.  You can also use a `DocumentFilter` to ensure that the field only contains numbers

Comment: Exactly. The problem is less *how* you're trying to get the information, but more ***when***. It must be done within a listener, one that is triggered when the user decides the information has been properly entered, such as within an ActionListener, not on component creation as you're doing.

Comment: When I try to define it in the actionListener method, it tells me it can't find the textbox

Comment: There's not enough context to your code to solve your problem

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @EFliegel I ran your code, it is actually fine after I added a validation before parsing. You also want to change your local variables to instance variables, especially for your components such as the textfields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your code, it actually works fine (without giving me `NumberFormatException`).

You get `NumberFormatException` probably because you attempted the following:

1. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the textfield when the field is empty
2. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the textfield when the field contains non-numeric input

You could add validations to your input before attempting to parse the textfield's content into integer:

```
public class BoxListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String s= price.getText();
        if(s.matches("[0-9]+"))               //Perform validation before parsing string
            inputPrice = Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
}
```

Also note that, instead of declaring `inputPrice` and your other components such as your textfields as local variables, I declared them as instance variables of `RatePanel`.

---

To declare your variables as instance variable instead of local variables:

```
class RatePanel extends JPanel{
    private JTextfield txtPrice;   // <--- declare here as instance variable
    private int inputPrice;        // <--- declare here as instance variable

    public RatePanel(){
        //If you declare in the constructor or other methods, they become local variables.
    }
}
```

Comment: I got the method working properly. Thank you all very much for your help, and apologies if I seemed unhelpful or noobish.

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to define it in the actionListener method, it tells me it
>   can't find the textbook

That is probably because you define 'price' as a local variable in the method that you create it. Your 'price' variable should be an instance variable that is visible to all methods in your class.

Comment: How would I change it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the code as written tries to access the text right after the text field is created, before the user has typed anything into it.  The code accessing the text should be inside the action listener.  If `ComboListener` is a class that you created, then the last two lines should be in its `actionPerformed` method; if you do it that way, make sure that the `price` variable is an instance variable or static variable (i.e., outside a method definition—whether to make it static and which class to put it in depends on how the rest of your code is structured).

An alternative way is to use an anonymous inner class, like this:

```
// the 'final' modifier is necessary for anonymous inner classes
// access local variables
final JTextField price = new JTextField();
price.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String inputText = price.getText();
        // do the conversion and other processing here...
    }
});
```

(I believe in newer versions of Java this can be abbreviated as

```
price.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
    String inputText = price.getText();
    // do the conversion and other processing here...
});
```

but I'm not 100% sure about that.)

Second, keep in mind that if you use `parseInt`, it'll only accept whole number values; things like `12.34` (with a decimal point) will cause an error.  The simplest way to fix this is to use `Double.parseDouble`, although using `double`s with prices can cause rounding errors, so it's not the best way to do it.  Also, make sure you don't put a `$` or `£` or `€` or whatever in the box; that could also cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading a JTextField immediately after creating it. At that point, it's empty empty string, which is not a valid number.

You should put that code in the listener where it will fire when the user presses Enter or something. And, additionaly, try to be nice to the user and show an error message instead of throwing an exception.